# DD-WRT: How can I set up my router as an ad-hoc?

Tags: dd-wrt, ad-hoc-network

Title says it all. 
The type of network I'm allowed to have in my area is an ad-hoc, but I don't want to use a whole computer just to have wireless.

So, is there a simple way to do this?

Maybe with software other than DD-WRT?

My router is a Netgear WRN3000L

Comment: do you mean ad-hoc or you do want mesh?

Answer (score 3):

You (and likely also whoever is telling you this) are confused. The only difference between an ad-hoc network and a "typical" wireless network is the context and terminology. I could set up an "ad-hoc" network from my iMac that shared an internet connection wirelessly, and it would be functionally identical to the same set-up with a router. For all I know, the network chipsets themselves may even be identical.

You need to get clarification on what is allowed and what is not. It is possible that you're simply not allowed to share your internet connection, in which case you can just fire up the router as-is and don't connect it to the internet.

Comment: +1 I suspect by "ad-hoc" the rule setter really means "not sharing your internet connection".  In which case simply not plugging the WAN port of the router into the provided internet drop would provide the same affect.  The connected devices would be able to share files but not surf the web.

Comment: Reason why only ad-hoc is allowed, is because WEP, and WPA are constantly De-Authed

Comment: @DerNalia Those aren't mutually exclusive. I can set up an ad-hoc network with WEP encryption from my iMac. That doesn't make it any more or less likely to be deauthed. Likewise, you could set up a network from your router that uses no encryption at all.

Answer (score 0):

Ad-hoc wireless networks are for connecting multiple wireless devices together without a central infrastructure (like a router).

From [About.com](http://compnetworking.about.com/cs/wirelessfaqs/f/adhocwireless.htm):

> On wireless computer networks, ad-hoc mode is a method for wireless devices to directly communicate with each other. Operating in ad-hoc mode allows all wireless devices within range of each other to discover and communicate in peer-to-peer fashion without involving central access points (including those built in to broadband wireless routers).

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_ad_hoc_network):

> A wireless ad hoc network is a decentralized type of wireless network. The network is ad hoc because it does not rely on a preexisting infrastructure, such as routers in wired networks or access points in managed (infrastructure) wireless networks.

So I would say there's no way to get *any* router to be set as "ad-hoc", so you're probably going to have to go back to whomever told you that and get some clarification from them. :)

Comment: Reason why only ad-hoc is allowed, is because WEP, and WPA are constantly De-Authed